html file not opening in my visual studio code editor
This file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding is what is showing me in my VSC when trying to open a file. How can i solve this problem? Thank you.

Open it in a different editor. If you get the same result, it's not a VS Code problem.
